# dpdk mbuf ref count check after detach

Tags: dpdk

I use mbuf from the intel dpdk library

I had a check in code for `mbuf` double release

I used to check if the `reference count <= 0`

Since the following change i can't check anymore this way since the reference count is 1 even after it is release to the pool http://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2017-January/056188.html

I there a way to check if the `mbuf` is detached(in the pool or out of the pool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we free and `refcnt` is 1 it's either the first or the second (double) free. So just use another mbuf field to distinct, i.e.:

```
if (refcnt == 1) {
    if (port != UINT16_MAX - 1) {
        // mark the mbuf
        port = UINT16_MAX - 1;
    } else {
        // already marked
        RTE_LOG(ERROR, USER1, "Double free!");
    }
}
```

### Update:

I just realized that you might not aware about the standard double free check in DPDK. Normally you just enable `RTE_LIBRTE_MEMPOOL_DEBUG` to check for double free and memory corruptions.

Another safe place to store the marker would be to allocate a private 8 byte area for each mbuf. See the `priv_size` argument in the `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()` for more details.

Comment: I can't really use the port because it is already used in code. So what you suggest is to add another field to the struct rte_mbuf like is_in_pool

Comment: My bad, abusing `port` field was not a good idea indeed. The best option would be to use the standard DPDK option for double free detection: `RTE_LIBRTE_MEMPOOL_DEBUG` or to allocate private data for each mbuf and put a flag there. I've updated the answer.